# GIT Basics - Master and Feature Branches

Tags: git

I have started a project and i have already completed one model out of 10 models.

But i just created a repository on bitbucket. I want to know if it is a good idea to push the model that i am currently done with to the master and the subsequent models to featured branches.

Comment: Is it just you working on the project?

Comment: yes i am the only one working on the project

Answer (score 0):

Git branches are generally used when the code needs to be working in between releases.  If I'm writing an application and want to add a big feature, this could take some time and the application might not compile while I'm writing that code.  If I do the modifications in a new branch I can apply bug fixes to the master branch and whatnot while playing with me new feature branch :)

In short: just use one branch :)